# Rounding, decimal places and split variables for 3 payments in js

Tags: javascript, math, var

Trying to make sense of some of the JavaScript `Math` functions and processing the output properly as strings.

What I need is the following for a 'pay in three instalments' function:

1. Divide a price in 3 (a/b/c)
2. Set them to two decimal places
3. Round down b and c
4. Add the remainders of b & c to a as a needs to be highest price, then b & c equal.
5. Input a into div class Instal1

Here's the code (did it all in variables) will this work? Nothing coming out in the jsfiddle result window...

http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/8e5Vr/17/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var handyTotal = jQuery(".price").text().replace(/\u00A3/g, '');

var aPrice = handyTotal / 3; // takes basket total & /3
var aPrice2dec = aPrice.toFixed(2); // converts to number with 2 decimal places
var bPrice = handyTotal / 3;
var bPrice2dec = bPrice.toFixed(2);
var cPrice = handyTotal / 3;
var cPrice2dec = cPrice.toFixed(2);

var bPriceFloored = Math.floor(bPrice2dec); // rounds down number 
var cPriceFloored = Math.floor(cPrice2dec);
var overflowbPrice = bPrice2dec - bPriceFloored; // finds amount to add to a
var overflowcPrice = cPrice2dec - cPriceFloored;
var calcaPrice = $(".Instal1").text(aPrice2dec + overflowbPrice + overflowcPrice); // adds b+c to a
});
```

Comment: You got typos here:
var bPriceFloored = Math.floor(bPricedec); // rounds down number 
var cPriceFloored = Math.floor(cPricedec);
I think its bPrice2dec and cPrice2dec

Comment: how about `b=c=Math.floor(total/3); a = total-b-c;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of fiddling and help above, here is the answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/8e5Vr/36/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

var handyTotal = jQuery(".price").text().replace(/\u00A3/g, '');

var aPrice = handyTotal / 3; // takes basket total & /3
var aPrice2dec = parseFloat(aPrice.toFixed(3)); // converts to number with 3 decimal places
var bPrice = handyTotal / 3;
var bPrice2dec = parseFloat(bPrice.toFixed(3));
var cPrice = handyTotal / 3;
var cPrice2dec = parseFloat(cPrice.toFixed(3));  

var bPriceFloored = Math.floor(bPrice2dec); // rounds down number 
var cPriceFloored = Math.floor(cPrice2dec);
var overflowbPrice = bPrice2dec - bPriceFloored; // finds amount to add to a
var overflowcPrice = cPrice2dec - cPriceFloored;
var calcaPrice = jQuery(".Instal1").text((parseFloat(aPrice2dec) + parseFloat(overflowbPrice) + parseFloat(overflowcPrice)).toFixed(2)); // adds b+c to a

var bPriceFlooredDiv = jQuery(".Instal2").text(Math.floor(bPrice2dec));
var cPriceFlooredDiv = jQuery(".Instal3").text(Math.floor(cPrice2dec));
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You have simple reference errors:

`bPricedec` and `cPricedec` is not defined. Fix them to `bPrice2dec` and `cPrice2dec` respectively.

Always keep an eye on the JavaScript console for error reports ;)

Comment: Ah yes, so I did. Edited now! The result isn't adding them together though?

Comment: That's because `toFixed` returns a string representation of the number passed to it so you are concatanating string values there. Use `parseFloat`: `(parseFloat(aPrice2dec) + parseFloat(overflowbPrice) + parseFloat(overflowcPrice)).toFixed(2)`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8e5Vr/27/

Answer (score 0):

You mistyped your variables in 3 places.
Mistyped variables are: bPricedec and cPricedec

Comment: Ah yes, so I did. Edited now! The result isn't adding them together though?

Comment: toFixed function returns a string type. So you should cast this string to float at the very beginning. See the code below:

var aPrice2dec = parseFloat(aPrice.toFixed(2));
var bPrice2dec = parseFloat(bPrice.toFixed(2));
var cPrice2dec = parseFloat(cPrice.toFixed(2));